# How can I implement a cache of geo-points

Tags: postgresql, caching, geospatial, postgis, geo

I am using a map service which, given a geo-circle (defined by coordinate and radius), returns a set of places in that area. I wish to cache the results returned by this map service.

I expect my cache to store two tables:

- A table *Places* of places returned by the service.
- A table *Circles* of areas which have had their places cached in the table *Places*.

Then, given an arbitrary new circle *C*, I want to efficiently test the cache for whether the area of *C* is entirely covered by the circles in the table *Circles*. If *C* is entirely covered, I have a cache hit, and I do not need to consult the map service. If *C* is not entirely covered, I must consult the map service and cache the result.

**Q1:** how can I store a set of geo-circles so that I can efficiently test whether the union of their areas entirely covers an arbitrary new circle?

Even with a solution to Q1, I may have a performance issue where a cache miss is very slight, and I make a request to the map service which barely adds to my cached area. To solve this, I want to be able to find an example point in *C* which is not covered by the circles, in order to use this as the center for a map service request. I will repeat this process until *C* is entirely covered.

**Q2:** how can I store the set of geo-circles so that, and in the event that their area does not entirely cover a given circle *C*, I can efficiently generate an example point in *C* which is not covered?

I expect to be using something like PostgreSQL with PostGIS to implement my cache, but I welcome other suggestions.

Comment: Do you really want a cache? Is index not enough (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xindex.html#XINDEX-ORDERING-OPS)?

Comment: @ЕгорРогов perhaps I wasn't clear: my PostGIS database is to be a cache of results from an external map service. I do not need a cache of queries against my database.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my hacky approach, which is essentially "rasterization".

Divide up the globe area into a large but finite number of small geo-tiles, which are defined by drawing a grid onto the lat/long plane.

Instead of a table of *Circles*, we keep a table of *Tiles* which have had their places cached in the *Places* table.

Given a geo-circle, we can efficiently generate the set of geo-tiles which are partially covered by the circle, and the set which are fully covered by the circle.

When inserting points into the cache, we mark each fully-covered tile as cached.

When probing the cache for circle *C*, if each tile fully- or partially-covered by *C* is in the *Tiles* table, we have a cache hit. Otherwise, we have a cache miss, and an example tile which is not cached, from which we can choose a point from this as the center of a circle to request from the map service.

This approach has flaws:

- Tiles vary in size and shape on the globe due to projection distortion.
- If a circle is too small, it may not fully cover any tiles, and so will never be marked as cached.